# Handle browser reload socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io, sails.js

There is a way in socket.io to create a timeout in the disconnected event, then check if the user has been reconnected ?

The idea is to emit data / save user state in database only if the user is not reconnected after timeout

**Edit**: Followed @Are Wojciechowski answer, I'm done with a multi tabs & F5 flood handler

https://gist.github.com/foohey/7696811

Comment: How will you emit data if the user isn't reconnected?

Comment: It's a game so I want to avoid connect/disconnect flood. After timeout I will update user state in database then emit a socket to the opposite player (this is a 1 VS 1 game)

Comment: can you fix the gist's link? it's broken

Answer (score 33, accepted):

There is a `socket.on('disconnect', function () { ... });`.
So you can just do

```
socket.on('disconnect', function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
         //do something
    }, 10000);
});
```

---

## EDIT 1:

I get it now. So maybe you should do something like this:

#### Client:

```
//right after connection
socket.emit('register', localstorage.getItem('gameUniqueId'));

//somewhere, when game starts
var randomlyGeneratedUID = Math.random().toString(36).substring(3,16) + +new Date;
localStorage.setItem('gameUniqueId', randomlyGeneratedUID);
```

#### Server:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    var player = null;

    socket.on('register', function (data) {
        if (data !== null) {
            //there was something in localstorage
            if (game.Players.existsUID(data)) {
                player = game.Players.getByUID(data);
                player.disconnected = false;
            } else {
                //timed out, create new player
            }
        } else {
            //localStorage is not set, create new player
        }
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        player.disconnected = true;
        setTimeout(function () {
            if (player.disconnected) player.delete();
        }, 10000);
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes I already tried that. But the problem is to talk between events. The idea is to set a session id in the disconnect event. then when the connected event is triggered, check if the user has previously disconnected and cancel (or not) the timeout

Comment: And now? I've changed the answer. I know that it is complicated, but I tried to simplify it (sic!). :)