# Socket.IO breaking on refresh (sockets timing out maybe?)

Tags: angularjs, socket.io

I created a chat app using socket.io, everything works very well except for when one of the users refresh. For instance:

If user A joins room 1, and user B joins room 1, they can communicate smoothly. If user A refreshes his browser, he can still send messages to user B in real time, but user B no longer sends user A messages in real time.

For some reason, when a user refreshes the page, he is no longer able to receive messages in real time. Here is how I have setup my chat system:

server side:

```
server.listen(port);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log("User Connected");

  socket.on('comment', function(data){
    //socket.broadcast.emit('comment', data);
    console.log('server sidecomment');
    socket.broadcast.to(data.chatId).emit('comment',data);
  });

  socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    console.log('user disconnected');
  });

  socket.on('join:room', function(data){
    socket.join(data.chatId);
    socket.broadcast.to(data.chatId).emit('join:room', data)
    console.log('joined room: ' + data.chatId);
  });

  socket.on('leave:room', function(data){
    socket.leave(data.chatId);
    console.log('left room: ' + data.chatId);
  })

  socket.on('typing', function(data){
    console.log('server side start typing');
    console.log(data);
    socket.broadcast.to(data.chatId).emit('typing',data);
  });

  socket.on('stoptyping', function(data){
    console.log('server side stop typing');
    socket.broadcast.to(data.chatId).emit('stoptyping');
  });



});
```

client side:

```
        $scope.$on("$destroy", function() {
            console.log('leaving page');
            socket.emit('leave:room', {
                'chatId': post.chatId
            });
            var leaveMessage = auth.currentUser() + ' has left';
            posts.addComment(post._id, {
                body: leaveMessage,
                author: 'server'
            }).success(function(comment) {
                $scope.post.comments.push(comment);
            });
        });


        socket.on('comment', function(data) {
            console.log('client side comment');
            $scope.post.comments.push(data);
        });
        socket.on('join:room', function(data) {
            var joinedMessage = {
                body: data.author + ' has joined',
                author: 'server'
            };
            $scope.post.comments.push(joinedMessage);
        });

        $scope.whenTyping = function() {
            socket.emit('typing', {
                'chatId': post.chatId,
                'author': auth.currentUser()
            });
        }

        $scope.notTyping = function() {
            socket.emit('stoptyping', {
                'chatId': post.chatId
            });
        }

        socket.on('typing', function(data) {
            $scope.typing = data.author + ' is typing';
        });

        socket.on('stoptyping', function() {
            $scope.typing = '';
        });
```

My question is: Is the socket being timed out? If it is, is there a way I can prevent it from being timed out?

Comment: Add code instead of screen shots..:\

Comment: changed the screenshots to code

Comment: When the page is refreshed, socket is disconnected and new connection is created. You will need to handle this re-connection. This may be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20260170/handle-browser-reload-socket-io